EF Core confused when resetting identity columns, causing exception
This is my seeding method:
public async Task Seed()
{
    dbContext.Database.Migrate();

    string dbName = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().Database;

    if (!dbName.EndsWith("_Tests"))
    {
        var tableNames = dbContext.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                .Select(t => t.GetTableName())
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();

        tableNames.ForEach(tableName =>
        {
            dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"ALTER TABLE {tableName} NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;");
        });

        tableNames.ForEach(tableName =>
        {
            dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"DELETE FROM {tableName};");
            dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(
                            $"IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('{tableName}') AND is_identity = 1) " +
                            $"BEGIN DBCC CHECKIDENT ('{tableName}', RESEED, 0); END");
        });

        tableNames.ForEach(tableName =>
        {
            dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"ALTER TABLE {tableName} CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;");
        });

        //Seed/insert data
        await SeedTable1();
        await SeedTable2();  // Depends on 1 for FK
        await SeedTable3(); // Depends on 1 and 2 for FK
    }
}

Everything worked fine until I added this line:
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(
                            $"IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('{tableName}') AND is_identity = 1) " +
                            $"BEGIN DBCC CHECKIDENT ('{tableName}', RESEED, 0); END");

That line resets the identity columns in the database, so every development restart the inserted items begin at PK = 1.
However due to this line I am getting errors in my seeding functions SeedTable2/3 any one which has foreign keys.
It is throwing the following error:

The value of 'CustomOptionMachineCategory (Dictionary<string, object>).AllowedOptionsId' is unknown when attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is not known.

This is a FK constraint, so I tried adding the following behind the inserting data/seeding.
tableNames.ForEach(tableName =>
        {
            dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"ALTER TABLE {tableName} CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;");
        });

But the error still continues to show up.
One thing I should note is that this error only occurs when the database is freshly dropped, and it gets run the first time. After that, the errors do not occur anymore.
It is very odd.

Drop the DB.
Remove the Database.Migrate line, so it doesn't migrate
Run migrations manually with command
Results in error
Start again
Works

OR

Drop the DB.
RUN
Error
Start again
Works

So I don't know I think it has to do with the initial state of the database which doesn't like the identity reset.
It seems like every time PENDING migrations run that has a corresponding seed with fk, either manually or via Database.Migrate, the error occurs.
What can I do to fix this?

Why do you even need to reset the identity? You shouldn't be doing that on a regular basis - this should be the total and utter exception - not the rule to do over and over ...

This only happens in development so in testing a feature I don't have to use absurd id's like 45, 999, . Because each time it reseeds the identity value goes up [amount of seeds]

??? I am asking for help, obviously I care. Its way more convenient in testing.

How is it more convenient for testing? The size of an id shouldn't affect testing... if it does I suggest its your testing you want to improve.

You should have edited the question you deleted. That said, it's probably the annoying bug that reseeding identity starts identity values at 0 when the table hasn't had any records yet. Use a method like this.

@GertArnold Thankyou for your insights, it might actually be this bug, I will keep you updated, thanks!
As for the question I deleted, yes I deleted it originally because I thought I found a workaround, but it wasnt, then undeleted it, but had to severely edit the question so I thought why not make a new one since the other one was irrelevant and this way people got updated by the change. Otherwise it would be a stale post
